# JAVA match string array to double array

Tags: java, arrays

I’m having trouble completing a certain part of a java project I’m working on.

These are my array’s I have made:

```
double [][] amortDB = new double[1000][4];

String [][] nameTable = new String[1000][6];
```

These are the instructions: **You will store the customer ID number, first name, last name, address, cell phone 
number, and age in a two-dim String array.**

**You will store the customer ID number, loan amount, and loan interest rate (as a #.# 
number), and desired monthly payment amount in a two-dim double array**

**Notice that the idea here is that these two arrays “sync” up. The first customer in 
the information array corresponds to the first customer in the loan info array, and 
etc**

So the trouble I’m having is matching the first position of each array to one another, as the customer ID should be matched in both. The user should be able to enter any string or double using scanner input for each requirement in both array. I’m just lost on how to match up a double array to a string array? Then after the customer ID’s are matched they should be able to call the other information from whatever is inputted under that customer.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *Notice that the idea here is that these two arrays “sync” up.* - a better way is to create a class than represents your data, and then have an Array or List of these Objects.

Comment: I was going to use classes, but the project is limited to not allowing so :/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? There are more elegant ways to solve this, but as an basic example it works.

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> idPositionMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int nameTableIndex = 0; nameTableIndex < nameTable.length; nameTableIndex++) {
        String id = nameTable[nameTableIndex][0];
        if (id != null) {
            double nameTableId = Double.valueOf(id); // Acutal conversion of String to double.
            int amortDbIndex = findAmortDbIdIndex(amortDB, nameTableId);
            if (amortDbIndex != -1) {
                idPositionMap.put(nameTableIndex, amortDbIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    idPositionMap.forEach((nameTableIndex, amortDbIndex) -> System.out.println("Index at nameTable: " + nameTableIndex + " Index at amortDb: " + amortDbIndex));

    private static int findAmortDbIdIndex(double[][] amortDb, double searchId) {
    for (int amortDbIndex = 0; amortDbIndex < amortDb.length; amortDbIndex++) {
        double id = amortDb[amortDbIndex][0];
        if (id != 0 && id == searchId) {
            return amortDbIndex;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The row positions for each Id is stored inside the `idPositionMap` with the position of nameTable's id as a key and the matching position of the same id inside amortDb.